# What precision are floating-point arithmetic operations done in?

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding, floating-point-precision, arithmetic-expressions

Consider two very simple multiplications below:

```
double result1;
long double result2;
float var1=3.1;
float var2=6.789;
double var3=87.45;
double var4=234.987;

result1=var1*var2;
result2=var3*var4;
```

Are multiplications by default done in a higher precision than the operands? I mean in case of first multiplication is it done in double precision and in case of second one in x86 architecture is it done in 80-bit extended-precision or we should cast operands in expressions to the higher precision ourselves like below?

```
result1=(double)var1*(double)var2;
result2=(long double)var3*(long double)var4;
```

What about other operations(add, division and remainder)? For example when adding more than two positive single-precision values, using extra significant bits of double-precision can decrease round-off errors if used to hold intermediate results of expression.

Comment: you should read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: how does that address the question?

Comment: This greatly depends on your compiler version.  The current versions of the big three all use SSE2 so use 64-bit precision.  Just look at the generated machine code to know.  You'll need better test code, it is done at compile-time for the snippets you posted.

Answer (score 8):

### Precision of floating-point computations

C++11 [incorporates](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/) the definition of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` from C99 in `cfloat`.

```
FLT_EVAL_METHOD     

Possible values:
-1 undetermined
 0 evaluate just to the range and precision of the type
 1 evaluate float and double as double, and long double as long double.
 2 evaluate all as long double
```

If your compiler defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` as 2, then the computations of `r1` and `r2`, and of `s1` and `s2` below are respectively equivalent:

```
double var3 = …;
double var4 = …;

double r1 = var3 * var4;
double r2 = (long double)var3 * (long double)var4;

long double s1 = var3 * var4;
long double s2 = (long double)var3 * (long double)var4;
```

If your compiler defines FLT_EVAL_METHOD as 2, then in all four computations above, the multiplication is done at the precision of the `long double` type.

However, if the compiler defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` as 0 or 1, `r1` and `r2`, and respectively `s1` and `s2`, aren't always the same. The multiplications when computing `r1` and `s1` are done at the precision of `double`. The multiplications when computing `r2` and `s2` are done at the precision of `long double`.

### Getting wide results from narrow arguments

If you are computing results that are destined to be stored in a wider result type than the type of the operands, as are `result1` and `result2` in your question, you should always convert the arguments to a type at least as wide as the target, as you do here:

```
result2=(long double)var3*(long double)var4;
```

Without this conversion (if you write `var3 * var4`), if the compiler's definition of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is 0 or 1, the product will be computed in the precision of `double`, which is a shame, since it is destined to be stored in a `long double`.

If the compiler defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` as 2, then the conversions in `(long double)var3*(long double)var4` are not necessary, but they do not hurt either: the expression means exactly the same thing with and without them.

### Digression: if the destination format is as narrow as the arguments, when is extended-precision for intermediate results better?

Paradoxically, for a single operation, rounding only once to the target precision is best. The only effect of computing a single multiplication in extended precision is that the result will be rounded to extended precision and then to `double` precision. This makes it [less accurate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding). In other words, with `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` 0 or 1, the result `r2` above is sometimes less accurate than `r1` because of double-rounding, and if the compiler uses IEEE 754 floating-point, never better.

The situation is different for larger expressions that contain several operations. For these, it is usually better to compute intermediate results in extended precision, either through explicit conversions or because the compiler uses `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2`. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725802/properties-of-80-bit-extended-precision-computations-starting-from-double-precis) and its accepted answer show that when computing with 80-bit extended precision intermediate computations for binary64 IEEE 754 arguments and results, the interpolation formula `u2 * (1.0 - u1) + u1 * u3` always yields a result between `u2` and `u3` for `u1` between 0 and 1. This property may not hold for binary64-precision intermediate computations because of the larger rounding errors then.

Comment: well I think you didn't get it correctly that double-rounding issue doesn't apply here at all! it's about intermediate/final results getting rounded more than once and here in your example no such thing happens just operands are converted to a higher precision(by the way this is not called rounding) and result gets rounded just one time to double(you might wanna know internally in FP unit, at least double/single multiplication is done in higher precision that's what Garp has mentioned in #1 in its post)

Comment: @Pooria I am glad that you found some help in another answer, but in the computation of `r2` (and in the computation of `r1` when FLT_EVAL_METHOD is 2), the final result does “get rounded more than once”, and that is called double-rounding. The result is computed and rounded to `long double` precision (you could argue against **this** use of the word “rounded”, although it is common to explain IEEE 754 basic operations as computing the real result and then rounding to the precision of the operation), and then rounded to `double` in order to be stored in memory.

Comment: @Pooria In the examples in your question, however, you are right that there is no double-rounding. I had not noticed this. I will expand my answer.

Comment: I don't seem to understand your point, what precision is result in that it needs to be rounded to long-double precision first and then double?

Comment: @Pooria When you assign the result to a variable of type `double`, it has to be converted from the extended format in the FPU to the format of `double`. C99 is very clear about this (although C++11 is not quite as clear).

Comment: I know but where is second time of rounding ?

Comment: @Pooria: that *is* the second rounding.  The first rounding is when the “infinitely-precise” result of the multiplication is rounded to working precision.

Comment: @Pooria Let us say you have an FPU for the 80-bit extended format. What I call the first rounding is because the FPU computes “as if” it calculated the exact result and then rounded to the 80-bit format. The second rounding happens when this result needs to be rounded from the 80-bit format to the 64-bit `double` format for storing in a variable.

Comment: so you mean in x86 a multiplication can be done in a more precision than 80-bit extended? doesn't it require registers with a number of significand bits near twice that of 80-bit extended?

Comment: @Pooria The result of the multiplication is **“as if”** the exact result had been computed and rounded. Depending on the algorithms used internally, this may require representing the exact result with twice the number of significand bits, or tricks can be used to save space (the three “guard bits” that Garp refers to in his answer). My speciality is not the hardware implementation, so I cannot say much. But the result should be “as if” the exact value had been computed and rounded.

Comment: I don't think "as if exactly computed" applies in case of doing arithmetic operation on extended precision, as quoted [here](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision), "It was designed to support a 32-bit "single precision" format and a 64-bit "double precision" format for encoding and interchanging floating point numbers. The double extended format was designed not to store data at higher precision as such, but rather primarily to allow for the computation of double results more reliably and accurately by minimizing overflow and roundoff-errors in intermediate calculations".

Comment: @Pooria The justification for the 80-bit extended format is what you quote above (which is also what much of my answer is about). And, separately, the definition of all IEEE 754 basic operations (+, -, *, / and sqrt) in all formats is that they must produce the same result as if the exact result had been computed and rounded to the destination format. This is why people sometimes use the word “rounding” about the result of a basic operation.

Comment: after reading [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#IEEE.C2.A0754_floating_point_support) what Garp said( FP multipliers use internally double the width of the operands to generate an intermediate result) doesn't seem to be true it depends on FLT_EVAL_METHOD that you said

Comment: @Pooria Garp's answer is about the internal implementation of one operation (either 64-bit wide or 80-bit wide). FLT_EVAL_METHOD is about what operation the compiler decides to use, so that a C++ program can be compiled for the 387 and also for a modern SSE2 processors, and that it is possible to predict what a given program will do. Garp's answer and my answer are talking about different aspects, they are not contradictory, only complementary.

Comment: well [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#IEEE.C2.A0754_floating_point_support) it says "FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2 indicates that all internal **intermediate computations** are performed by default at high precision (long double) where available" and " FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 1 **performs all internal intermediate expressions** in double precision (unless an operand is long double)" this means to me the operation itself is done at a specific precision not just that result is rounded to that precision, doesn't "computing at a precision" also mean "computing internally in FP at a precision"?

Comment: @Pooria What happens inside the FPU is only the FPU designer's problem. On a webpage that discusses C99, “computing at a precision P” means “using the instruction that takes operands of width P and produces a correctly rounded result of width P”, regardless of how this instruction is implemented (if the operation is a multiplication, it is likely implemented with a wider internal result in the processor, as Garp said, but that wider result that temporarily exists in the FPU is not stored).

Comment: as I said unfortunately "performing internal intermediate computations/expressions at a specific precision" has a very distinct meaning preventing the idea of for example using long-double precision registers for computing at double precision, text would have easily meant something other than it if it was meant to

Comment: @PascalCuoq Ok looks like you are right by "computing at a precision P means using the instruction that takes operands of width P and produces a correctly rounded result of width P regardless of how this instruction is implemented", according to [this](http://lslwww.epfl.ch/pages/teaching/cours_lsl/sl_info/FPMultiplier.pdf) looks like in FPU internally double the width of significand of operands(+2 in case there were hidden bits) is used to produce product of significand bits, I had a wrong idea of internal FPU workings :)

Comment: I wonder why my 1980s compilers for the 8087 used behavior equivalent to FLT_EVAL_METHOD==2 cleanly and consistently, but over the years that gave way to loosy-goosy semantics?  Computing intermediate results as `long double` is easier for a compiler than trying to have the intermediate result type vary with the operand type, and in most non-contrived situations gives more useful results. While 80-bit intermediate type won't guarantee that `d4=d1+d2+d3;` will be perfectly evaluated for all values of d1, d2, and d3, it will yield good results easily when the values are of comparable magnitudes.

Comment: By comparison, the amount of code required to compute a simple sum like `d4=d1+d2+d3;` for values of similar magnitudes ends up being much more cumbersome if intermediate result can't be computed using extended precision.

Answer (score 2):

1. For floating point multiplication: FP multipliers use internally double the width of the operands to generate an intermediate result, which equals the real result within an infinite precision, and then round it to the target precision. Thus you should not worry about multiplication. The result is correctly rounded.
2. For floating point addition, the result is also correctly rounded as standard FP adders use extra sufficient 3 guard bits to compute a correctly rounded result.
3. For division, remainder and other complicated functions, like transcendentals such as sin, log, exp, etc... it depends mainly on the architecture and the used libraries. I recommend you to use the MPFR library if you seek correctly rounded results for division or any other complicated function.

Comment: interestingly you addressed my main concern in #1, but in case of x86 and long double(80-bit extended precision) there are no registers to hold double the width am I right? I mean there are quadruples but not in x86 :)

Comment: Thank you, but what I meant by that "multipliers use internally double the width of the operands" that this totally executed within the multiplier itself without your intervention. You will get your correctly rounded result no matter what the precision.For example if the operands are of 80 bits, i.e. 64 bits for mantissa, the multiplier compute a 124 bit long intermediate result then round it again to a 64 bit long result,then it saves it to your destination register along with the exponent and sign,constituting a 80 bit long result.TLDR you should not worry for FP addition and multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

The *usual arthimetic conversions* for floating point types are applied before multiplication, division, and modulus:

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands and determine the type of the result.
>
> §5.6 [expr.mul]

Similarly for addition and subtraction:

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed for operands of arithmetic or enumeration type.
>
> §5.7 [expr.add]

The *usual arithmetic conversions* for floating point types are laid out in the standard as follows:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions, which are defined as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> — If either operand is of type `long double`, the other shall be converted to `long double`.
>
> — Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, the other shall be converted to `double`.
>
> — Otherwise, if either operand is `float`, the other shall be converted to `float`.
>
> §5 [expr]

The actual form/precision of these floating point types is implementation-defined:

> The type `double` provides at least as much precision as `float`, and the type `long double` provides at least as much precision as `double`.  The set of values of the type `float` is a subset of the set of values of the type `double`; the set of values of the type `double` is a subset of the set of values of the type `long double`. The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined.
>
> §3.9.1 [basic.fundamental]

Comment: This answer misses the crux of the question; what precision are these calculations performed in behind the scenes?

Comment: That is implementation defined.  See §3.9.1 [basic.fundamental].

Comment: I could only reference  std::limits<double> and std::limits<long double> classes

Comment: You mean [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but for constant floating-point values (such as the ones specified in your question), the method that yields the least amount of precision-loss would be using the rational representation of each value as an integer numerator divided by an integer denominator, and perform as many integer-multiplications as possible before the actual floating-point-division.

For the floating-point values specified in your question:

```
int var1_num = 31;
int var1_den = 10;
int var2_num = 6789;
int var2_den = 1000;
int var3_num = 8745;
int var3_den = 100;
int var4_num = 234987;
int var4_den = 1000;
double result1 = (double)(var1_num*var2_num)/(var1_den*var2_den);
long double result2 = (long double)(var3_num*var4_num)/(var3_den*var4_den);
```

If any of the integer-products are too large to fit in an `int`, then you can use larger integer types:

```
unsigned int
signed   long
unsigned long
signed   long long
unsigned long long
```